# Is the post-modifier "to write" part of a noun phrase in "letters to write"?

Tags: phrases, post-modifier

> I have *letters* **to write**.

Is the post-modifier "to write" forming a noun phrase with the noun "letters"?

Answer (score 4):

> *I have* [*letters to write*].

Yes, the bracketed constituent is a noun phrase with the noun "letters" as head.

"To write" is an infinitival relative clause post-modifying "letters". It has a modal meaning comparable to that expressed in finite relative clauses by *can* or *should*.

Compare: *I have letters I can/should write.*

Comment: +1. But is it also possible to analyze "letters" as a direct object of "have" and "to write" as its catenative complement? Sorry if I confused the two. Thanks in advance for your kind response.

Comment: @user424874 I don't think so. I take the whole of "letters to write" as object of "have".  Complex catenatives with "have" are causative, as in "I'll have Ed write them a letter".

Comment: Thanks for making it clear for me.

Comment: Note that here the prepositional phrase *to write* specifies the letters being mentioned. Not so in, for example, *I have my mother to thank for my love of music*, since we are issued but one mother each.

Comment: So the position of the phrase in the sentence changes its role?  "I have to see some people" vs "I have some people to see".

Comment: The meaning is similar to "I have to write letters", but emphasizes the letters rather than the writing.